# jTextArea not showing incoming message in method

Tags: java, jtextarea

```
public void setMsg(String msg) {

    txtArea1.append(msg);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg);
}
```

Messge are displaying on Message dialog but not displaying in Text Area..wahy?

Comment: thats a rather incomplete code, but have you tried to repaint the textarea?

Comment: @Paul, you don't need to invoke repaint(). Swing components are smart enough to repaint themselves when a property is changed.

Comment: If the text doesn't display in the text area, then the text area was not added to the GUI. Maybe you defined the txtArea1 variable twice? If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax looks correct, try shutting down Eclipse-Netbeans whatever/cleaning project.